# Python Selenium find elements by class name doesn't work

Tags: pandas, selenium

[image]

I am trying to get the image link from this page.

```
 def save_score(self):
        element_lst = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ingredient-score score-popup')
        score_lst = [element.get_attribute('src') for element in element_lst]
        return len(element_lst)
```

But it seems like selenium can't get the elements when I am finding it by the class name.
In this table I have 8 image links that I want to scrape.
Is there any way around to achieve this? Maybe using Xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you're using class as Selector we don't use space between the values, instead of  "*ingredient-score score-popup*" try with "*ingredient-score.score-popup*". I leave this reference
[page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Since that element has multiple class names you should use css_selector or xpath. Lie this:

```
def save_score(self):
        element_lst = self.driver.find_elements_by_css-selector('img.ingredient-score.score-popup')
        score_lst = [element.get_attribute('src') for element in element_lst]
        return len(element_lst)
```

or

```
def save_score(self):
        element_lst = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[@lcass="ingredient-score score-popup"]')
        score_lst = [element.get_attribute('src') for element in element_lst]
        return len(element_lst)
```